# How to make Elasticsearch date_histogram facet work on nested items

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Kibana 3 to query my Elasticsearch server. Kibana offers a date_histogram visualization panel to display prices that I have gathered for products. Each product can contain an arbitrary amount of prices with an according date. Prices are implemented as nested fields within each document.

Kibana creates the below query which works fine when applied to **all** documents.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost.com:9200/vendor2/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "facets": {
    "1": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "key_field": "Prices.Fetched",
        "value_field": "Prices.Price",
        "interval": "1m"
      },
      "nested": "Prices",
      "facet_filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*"
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match_all": {}
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "match_all": {}
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}'
```

The problem comes up, when I try to use the date_histogram to visualize price movements over time for a **single** product. Kibana offers the ability to filter down to a certain document. For example based on its id/sku.

However, then the date_histogram facet stays empty.

This is an example... Can anyone please advise what could be wrong with the query?

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost.com:9200/vendor2/_search?pretty' -d '{   "facets": {
    "1": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "key_field": "Prices.Fetched",
        "value_field": "Prices.Price",
        "interval": "1m"
      },
      "nested": "Prices",
      "facet_filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*"
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match_all": {}
                    },
                    {
                      "fquery": {
                        "query": {
                          "field": {
                            "sku": {
                              "query": "\"AZF78FH77\""
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "_cache": true
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "match_all": {}
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }   },   "size": 0 }'
```

Comment: not sure but... what about querying and then performing facet, rather than applying a facet filter query? So the form would be: ```{
    "query" : {
        ...your query here
    },
    "facets" : {
        "histo1" : {
            "date_histogram" : { . date facet here..}
        }
    }
}```

Comment: I will try that. But that means, that I need to refactor the date_histogram panel in Kibana to build the query differently. I'd really like to understand, why the above approach doesn't work because that's what Kibana comes up with right now. (I made a little modification to the panel by adding the "nested" property to the method which builds the ES query. But the rest is Kibana standard...

Comment: does a simple query for docs containing ```"sku": {"query": "\"AZF78FH77\""}``` return any docs?

Comment: Hi Mcconlin, thanks for your guidance. I tried that query structure with success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the double quotes that you have included in your query (notice the escaped quotes in the query). This will cause ElasticSearch to look for SKUs of '"AZF78FH77"', rather than 'AZF78FH77'

Try querying in Kibana without quotes in the query box.

Comment: How do you add queries to the existing histogram? I want to add my own queries to show when issues were created and open. I am able to run those queries on Marvel/Sense trying to find a way to add it to Kibana